# How can I wrap contents of a textbox that's next to a picture control?

Tags: activereports

I have the following defined in Active Reports 8 (a picture control with a `border--shape--next` to textbox fields):

[image]

I have more textbox fields below the two defined here, but this is just to illustrate my issue.

Anyway, how do I get the first textbox to wrap without overlapping the second textbox like below?

[image]

When I get rid of the picture and shape on the left, everything wraps as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a known issue and is caused when controls are placed adjacent to each other and one side of the control has a larger height as compared to the ones on the other. Considering your example, let's say the top textbox is TextBox1 and the bottom one is TextBox2. You can handle the BeforePrint event of the Detail section and resolve this issue. For example take a look at the code below:

```
public void Detail_BeforePrint()
{
    TextBox2.Top = TextBox1.Top + TextBox1.Height;
}
```

Hope this helps.